# Como evitar la selección de texto y elementos al dar doble click sobre elementos html?

Tags: html5

alguien sabe como evitar que al dar doble click sobre un elemento(como ejemplo sobre un icono de un menú desplegable) se seleccione el texto u otros elementos de una pagina HTML?

*[image: *texto en negrita*]*

Comment: mejora tu pregunta para que entendamos tu duda porfavor.

Comment: Me imagino que lo que buscas es algo como [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), pero no tengo muy claro si lo que quieres es evitar que se seleccione o controlar el evento de pulsar sobre texto.

Comment: Solo evitar que se seleccionen los elementos cuando hago doble click sobre el icono del menú desplegable

Comment: Al dar doble click sobre el menú aparecen los cuadros de selección sobre el texto y algunos elementos

Comment: Gracias, ya lo solucioné con esa propiedad de user-select

Answer (score 1):

Tal como le comenta @Alvaro-Montoro usando `user-select` puede lograr esto, he notado que ha comentado que esta resuelto, pero aquí le dejo un ejemplo por si otro usuario tiene la misma cuestionante en algún momento.

Con `jquery` puede intentar algo como esto:

```
 $(element).mousedown(function(){ return false; })
```

Y con `CSS` algo así:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

---

Aquí un ejemplo:

```css
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Versión sin prefijo, actualmente
                                      compatible con Chrome y Opera */
```

```html
<p>
  Texto Seleccionable.
</p>
<p class="noselect">
 Texto NO seleccionable.
</p>
```

---

Nota: El prefijo `-khtml-` no es obligatorio, ver: [¿Qué compatibilidad pierdo al eliminar el prefijo -khtml-vendor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687680/what-compatibility-do-i-lose-when-dropping-the-khtml-vendor-prefix) (Traducir del ingles)

> Tenga en cuenta que es una característica **no estándar** (es decir, no forma parte de ninguna especificación). No se garantiza que funcione en todas partes, y puede haber diferencias en la implementación entre navegadores y en el futuro los navegadores pueden dejar de brindar soporte.
>
> Para mas información consulte este Post SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/8933039